# Why FLTK window become unresizable with mouse after resize() was called?

Tags: c++, fltk

Why I cannot resize the window once `window.size()` or `window.resize()` was called? How to fix this?

```
#include <FL/Fl.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Window.H>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  Fl_Window window(0, 0, 110, 110);
  window.position(0, 0);
//  window.size(300, 300); <--uncomment this, and cannot resize window with the mouse!
  window.show(argc,argv);
  return Fl::run();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

size(width, height) is basically a shortcut to resize(x(), y(), width, height).  It fixes the size of the widget.

If you want the window to be resizable, call

```
window.resizable(&window);
```

Have a look at subwindow.cxx in the test programs from the distribution tarball.

Comment: Ok, the trick was to call `window.resizable(window)` _right after the constructor_

Comment: This introduces proportional resizing, which might not be what you want. More details can be found in https://www.fltk.org/doc-1.4/resize.html (it also works for FLTK 1.3).

Comment: It only introduces proportional resizing if a widget or group of widgets in the dialog is marked as resizable.  If only the dialog is resizable then all widgets stay where they are and only the dialog resizes.